# Updating HTML after Ajax or jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've created two calls, one is ajax call to my controller, and other one is jquery call. I've did both just to  check if my HTML would update once I trigger the event... But none of these methods update my HTML (it stays the same way). Here are the methods:

Method #1:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function(){
       var startDate =  $.trim($("#startDate").val());
       var endDate =  $.trim($("#endDate").val());
       $.post("/history/list",{'startDate':startDate,"endDate":endDate},function(data){
           var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#historyList').html();
           $('#historyList').append(result);
           console.log(result);
// the result is displayed correctly in the console...
       });
    });
// This is supposed to update my HTML in the browser now, but it's not showing anything new...
```

Method #2:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    console.clear();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/history/list",
        data: {
            startDate: $('#startDate').val(),
            endDate: $('#endDate').val(),
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#historyList').html();
            $('#historyList').append(result);
            console.log(result);
// the result is displayed correctly in the  console...
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            //$('#showresults').slideDown('slow')
        }
    });
});
```

None of these methods update my HTML once the call is finished and data is returned... The data object holds the HTML as the result, and I'd like that HTML in the data object replaces everything what is in div tag under id **#historyList**.. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. I'm using chrome browser (if this is a useful information)

Comment: Can you please tell me about that URL ("/history/list") is that file or directory ?

Comment: Please post server side code too...

Comment: /history <- is a controller and list is an action... I'm using Zend framework 2

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the result. Could you use .html, like so:

```
$('#historyList').html(data);
```

Or the whole code like this.

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            console.clear();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/history/list",
                data: {
                    startDate: $('#startDate').val(),
                    endDate: $('#endDate').val(),
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#historyList').html(data);
                    console.log(result);
// the result is displayed correctly in the  console...
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                },
                complete: function (xhr, status) {
                    //$('#showresults').slideDown('slow')
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Could you post what the "data" is?

Comment: Hey I couldn't paste the HTML since its well over 30000 characthers, its way above the limit that stackoverflow lets me to post...

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achive? I'm not understanding.. You can't paste a WHOLE html-page inside your div...

Comment: I'm trying to update part of my  HTML, or just refreshing the whole page with the results  that are returned when I send out my two parameters: start date and end date...

Comment: Then you shouldn't return a HTML-page, but just a part of the html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112915/discussion-between-perkes456-and-jesper-hojer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$('#historyList')` is not an empty array and exists in the DOM. If it exists,

```
$('#historyList').html(data);
```

should solve the problem.

Correct me, if my understanding of the question is wrong.